# Extract substring that starts and ends with symbol and replace with variable in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to extract a word from a string in Python that's padded with `%%` on each side, and replace it with a variable value based on the value of the substring.
Something like this:

```
 name1 = "Alice"
 name2 = "Bob"
 date = datetime.datetime.now()

 input = "Hi, my name is %%name1%%. Today is %%date%%"
 output = ##Find and Replace Line Here
 print output
```

which would result in `"Hi, my name is Bob. Today is 2015-10-19 23:07:17.342105"`.

I found the `replace()` method, I'm only able to find and replace the whole substring with a preset value, like this:

```
print input.replace("%%name0%%", "name1")
```

Is there a way to first extract the value of a substring before replacing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you wouldn't just use python's format string substitution?

```
>>> args = {
...     'name1': "Alice",
...     'name2': "Bob",
...     'date': datetime.datetime.now()
... }
>>> print "Hi, my name is {name1}. Today is {date}".format(**args)
Hi, my name is Alice. Today is 2015-10-20 01:21:36.020427
```

You could always map `%%name1%%` to `{name1}` and do the above if you must use `%%name1%%`

Comment: is this safe to use on untrusted user input from the web? Can the user pass in a command?

Comment: Yes its safe in the sense this is purely string substitution, they can string substitute anything in the `args` dictionary.